# Asp.Net: Convert string to long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to persist geolocation data gotten by the google.maps.Geocoder(). 
From javascript I set the values into an (actually) hidden element in html (which is working fine):

```
document.getElementById("longitude").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
document.getElementById("latitude").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
```

From there I want to pass the values into the controller:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Longitude, new { id = "longitude", type = "number" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Latitude, new { id = "latitude", type = "number"})
```

Depending on the decimal seperator I get either a validation error or the values for longitude and latitude are not set to the model. Both properties are type of **long**.

Why can't Asp.Net parse the values automatically?
I am quite new to Asp.Net but I know I could else:

- write my own html-helper
- pass a view model into my controller or
- persisting the string values

Which way should I prefer?

Thanks, Rico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting errors because `long` stores large 64-bit integer values (it's actually `Int64` behind the scenes), not floating point values.

If you want your code to work with floating point values, you'll need to use something like `float` or `double`.

Comment: Ahhh... sometimes I don't see the wood for the trees :-) Of course, I need to use double instead... Sorry for my stupidness :-)